# Android ExpandableListView with button

Tags: android, scrollview, expandable

i want to use expandablelist with scroolview

how can i do this (one screen 2 action )

top  --> horizontal scrollview (some image left to right)
down --> expandableListView     (top to down)

|

screen

---

horizontal scrollview (some image)

---

expandableListView (some group, child)

---

thank you.

Comment: Show some effort! What have you tried so far? What isn't working as expected? Or how about checking out the offical documentation? [http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of expandablelist with scrollview  use spinner.

```
       Spinner sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
          Dbhelper db=new Dbhelper(this);
           Cursor c1=db.rawQuery("select accNo from Account4 where bankName='"+str+"'",null);
           acc=new String[c1.getCount()];
           while(c1.moveToNext()){
           acc[i]=c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("accNo"));
           i++;
          }

   ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,acc);

       sp1.setAdapter(adp);

       c1.close();
```